Create enum for json schema by reference to property values of json files held in subpages of intranet site
I'm adding to a json schema (version draft-07) where I want a property to be defined as one of a list of the results of a specific property that is stored in many json files accessible via my intranet.
So, a simpler example would be: assume the intranet site is "https://mycompany.com/inventory/teams.json" and the property I wish to build an enum from is called "slug", then this should be a valid definition for the schema:
"teams": {
    "description": "An array of teams in the inventory",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "oneOf": [
            {
             "const": {
                 "$ref": "https://mycompany.com/inventory/teams.json#/slug"
                       }
              }
         ]
    }
}

In the example above, I would expect that a valid result would only be one of the "slug" properties from any object on that page. Do correct me if I'm wrong.
Now, the harder problem I have is that I wish to reference this property where each json object is itself a subpage to "https://mycompany.com/inventory/teams.json". Is there a way to reference all of those?
For example, would
"$ref": "https://mycompany.com/inventory/teams.json/*/#/slug"

or something similar work?

In JSON Schema, $ref must point to a schema; it can't point to any other kind of data.
Secondly, it only works as part of a schema, and const just carries data.  So what you've configured in
{
  "const": {
    "$ref": "https://mycompany.com/inventory/teams.json#/slug"
  }
}

is for the value to be exactly the JSON object
{
  "$ref": "https://mycompany.com/inventory/teams.json#/slug"
}

This won't be processed as a schema.
The thing you want, grabbing the values from somewhere else to be used in a keyword isn't supported out of the box.  You'll need custom functionality to do that.  Your options are:

Pre-process the schema so that you have a completed schema prior to evaluation.
Use a custom keyword, like my data keyword.


Thanks for correcting me and explaining that. I'll have to write something to extend the validator instead
